# Label and group radio buttons horizontally aligned

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have a label and group radio button (two) and i want to make it to be horizontally aligned like in the picture.

[image]

I tried this code:

```
`<ion-row radio-group [(ngModel)]="Sexe">
  <ion-col>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label color="primary">Sexe</ion-label>
        <ion-radio value="Mr"></ion-radio>
        <ion-radio value="Mme"></ion-radio>
      </ion-item>
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>`
```

and also this code:

```
`<ion-row radio-group [(ngModel)]="Sexe">
  <ion-col>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label color="primary">Sexe</ion-label>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-radio value="Mr"></ion-radio>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
          <ion-radio value="Mme"></ion-radio>
      </ion-item>
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>`
```

But i don't have the result that I want.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use `ion-row` and `ion-col` elements for that. Please take a look at [this working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/AdFPOUaufyFYXqBxNiGg?p=preview).

```
  <ion-row radio-group [(ngModel)]="sexe">
    <ion-col>
      <ion-item>
        Sexe
      </ion-item>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Homme</ion-label>
        <ion-radio value="homme"></ion-radio>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col>
      <ion-item>
       <ion-label>Femme</ion-label>
        <ion-radio value="femme"></ion-radio>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
```

Since we use a single row and three columns, the title and the radio items will be placed all in the same row (horizontally aligned).

Answer (score 1):

```
<ion-row>
        <ion-label class="ion-label" color=dark>Save</ion-label>
      </ion-row>
      <ion-row radio-group [(ngModel)]="relationship" class="item">

            <ion-col>
                    <ion-radio value="manually" checked></ion-radio>
                    <ion-label>Manually</ion-label>
            </ion-col>

            <ion-col>
                    <ion-radio value="automatic"></ion-radio>
                    <ion-label>Automatically</ion-label>
            </ion-col>

    </ion-row>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ion-radio-group>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col size="4">
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Site Visit</ion-label>
        <ion-radio value="site"></ion-radio>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col size="4">
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Call</ion-label>
        <ion-radio value="call"></ion-radio>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col size="4">
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Final Deal</ion-label>
        <ion-radio value="deal"></ion-radio>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-radio-group>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ion-radio-group value="biff">
 <table><tr>
  <td>
   <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Biff</ion-label>
    <ion-radio  value="biff"></ion-radio>
   </ion-item>
  </td>
  <td>
   <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Griff</ion-label>
    <ion-radio  value="griff"></ion-radio>
   </ion-item>
  </td></tr>
 </table>
 </ion-radio-group>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).